# How to sarcastically say "good job"

Tags: сленг

I took Russian in university and can talk a little. A few days ago my Russian friend lost his keys and I wanted to sarcastically say "nice job" in Russian, but I didn't really know what was the proper thing to say and said "*хорошая работа*". He laughed at me for saying that.

- What is the proper thing to say?
- Is there a usual noun or slang for such an incident?

Comment: "хорошая работа" - i like it. i think, he laughed because it's a good joke, it's realy fun. in a similar situation i would say хорошая работа too, or успех!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can say the word **молодец**, but with sarcastic intonation. In Russian you can change a lot with intonation.

Comment: Like this answer better, I used it today and seemed and worked just fine

Comment: You could amplify the effect by drawling the 'e' a bit ("молодееец") and shaking your head slowly while uttering the word.

Comment: There is a variant of _молодец_ – _молодца_ (do not confuse with genitive case). It seems to me, it contains more sarcasm than regular form even without special intonation, so it can be used in writing. For emphasis it often spelled phonetically: _маладца_ or even _малаца_.

Answer (score 9):

Молодец!

Мá-лá-дéц! or Ну ты молодéц! (more obvious sarcasm)

Ну ты молодец, блин! (sarcasm + mild annoyance)

Постарался, ничё не скажешь! (sarcasm + mild reproach)

Answer (score 4):

Obviously I'm not Russian, however I have seen the word **красава** used in this way, and I believe it means something like "good one!" "good going!" The natives will have to weigh in.

Comment: One might stretch the second **a** to come off as being more sarcastic: **краса-ава!**

Answer (score 2):

Tiny list, if you will have opportunity again ))

not good at smiles but added some, Big letters in words = emphasis, all at once or any of

more optimistic, for my opinion:

```
Отличненько, ты просто мОлОдЕц(молодцА) :p
МолодцаАа :p
Заме-чАтельно o^
Удачник, ты просто Удачник, заведи собаку :).
```

more pessimistic:

```
Молодца
Ну ты крут, Что.
КрутоОo
```

Answer (score 0):

"Хорошая работа" is fine, though you can emphasize it with "Отличная работа"

Comment: В данном конкретном случае, когда кто-то потерял ключи "работы" как таковой не было сделано, поэтому здесь подходит только "молодец". Вот если бы он что-то делал (табуретку например) а она вышла кривой, тогда можно было бы о работе говорить.

Answer (score 0):

friends.
Weather I do not know to what extent very much sarcastic it may or may not sound,
 but us Russians on such events normally say " Ну, ты даешь!" . 
I would not very strongly recommend use of an adjective "молодец"
for any Russisn normally answers to this word "Молодцы в конюшне стоят", 
 that is "Good horses in the stable stay" ."Молодец"="good horse"

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your good words is opposite to a bad situation means it's a sarcasm, just like in English I believe, so you can say anything you would say to complement your friend for his ‘nice job’ («хорошая работа», «отлично сработано», «отлично», «прекрасно», «круто» (kinda slang), «супер», «молодец», etc.).